# Select case not working for sum of quantity on inventory

Tags: sql

I've two tables: Requirement table & inventory table.

First table : Required quantity

```
| Ship From | Material | Req Date  | Req Quantity | Fulfill (Y/N)? |
|-----------|----------|-----------|--------------|----------------|
|        21 | Mat1     | 7/1/2018  |           46 |                |
|        21 | Mat1     | 8/19/2018 |           33 |                |
|        21 | Mat1     | 9/2/2018  |           99 |                |
|        21 | Mat1     | 9/2/2018  |            4 |                |
|       106 | Mat1     | 9/16/2018 |           92 |                |
|       106 | Mat1     | 8/19/2018 |          126 |                |
|       457 | Mat2     | 8/19/2018 |          126 |                |
|       457 | Mat2     | 9/10/2018 |          126 |                |
|       457 | Mat2     | 9/10/2018 |          126 |                |
|       457 | Mat2     | 9/10/2018 |           24 |                |
|       478 | Mat2     | 9/2/2018  |           52 |                |
|       478 | Mat2     | 9/10/2018 |           73 |                |
|       478 | Mat2     | 9/10/2018 |           18 |                |
|       478 | Mat2     | 9/16/2018 |           30 |                |
```

Second Table : Available Inventory

```
 ----------- ---------- -------------------- --------------- 
  Ship From   Material   Inv Available Date   Available Qty  
 ----------- ---------- -------------------- --------------- 
         21   Mat1       6/15/2018                       46  
         21   Mat1       6/15/2018                       33  
         21   Mat1       7/2/2018                        99  
         21   Mat1       10/2/2018                        4  
        106   Mat1       10/16/2018                      92  
        106   Mat1       7/19/2018                      126  
        457   Mat2       8/19/2018                      126  
        457   Mat2       8/10/2018                      126  
        478   Mat2       9/16/2018                       30  
        478   Mat2       10/2/2018                       52
```

Need to check whether we have enough inventory(sum(Available qty)) in the second table on or before Inv available date and mark on table1 whether we can fulfill the order.

Please note we need to decrement sum of qty from table 2 for orders fulfilled on table 1.

I've 70k rows in table1 and 600k rows in table2.

```
Select
    Y1.Material,
    Y1.[Order Qty],
    Y1.[Ship From],
    Y1.[Code Date] as Req_date,
    I1.[Code Date] as Inv_date,
    (SELECT CASE WHEN (Select SUM(I1.Quantity) as sum_qty FROM YOTC_ALL Y1, Inventory I1 WHERE Y1.Material = I1.Material AND Y1.[Ship From] = I1.[Ship From] AND 
    Y1.[Code Date] > = I1.[Code Date]) > Y1.[Order Qty]) THEN "Y" ELSE "N"
FROM
    YOTC_ALL Y1,
    Inventory I1
WHERE
    Y1.Material = I1.Material AND
    Y1.[Ship From] = I1.[Ship From] AND
    Y1.[Code Date] > = I1.[Code Date]
GROUP BY
    I1.[Code Date],
    Y1.Material,
    Y1.[Order Qty],
    Y1.[Ship From],
    Y1.[Code Date];
```

I've tried the above query but cannot seem to get it to work. Help please!!!

Comment: what does your YOTC_ALL table looks like?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Some non-ANSI SQL syntax there...)

Comment: My bad, first table is YOTC_ALL table. I'm using MS SQL.